# How can I open a file in drawboard pdf via command line? (Windows Store App)

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-store-app

Usually you can open a file with an app by passing the file as the first command line argument

```
programe.exe file.pdf
```

For Apps from the Windows Store it seems like you have to use a different method. Even just running the app (without passing an argument) isn't as straight forward (see [How to open a Windows store app from command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/1543363/how-to-open-a-windows-store-app-from-command-line/1543441)).

I already found the `AppxManifest.xml` at `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Drawboard.DrawboardPDF_5.35.6.0_x64__gqbn7fs4pywxm`. The interesting part seems to be

```
...
      <Extensions>
        <uap:Extension Category="windows.shareTarget">
          <uap:ShareTarget Description="Drawboard PDF">
            <uap:SupportedFileTypes>
              <uap:FileType>.pdf</uap:FileType>
              <uap:FileType>.jpg</uap:FileType>
              <uap:FileType>.png</uap:FileType>
            </uap:SupportedFileTypes>
          </uap:ShareTarget>
        </uap:Extension>
        <uap:Extension Category="windows.search" />
        <uap:Extension Category="windows.protocol">
          <uap:Protocol Name="drawboardpdf">
            <uap:Logo>Assets\Logos\Square44x44\Logo.png</uap:Logo>
            <uap:DisplayName>Drawboard PDF</uap:DisplayName>
          </uap:Protocol>
        </uap:Extension>
        <uap:Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
          <uap:FileTypeAssociation Name="pdf">
            <uap:Logo>Assets\Logos\Square44x44\Logo.png</uap:Logo>
            <uap:SupportedFileTypes>
              <uap:FileType>.pdf</uap:FileType>
              <uap:FileType>.jpeg</uap:FileType>
              <uap:FileType>.jpg</uap:FileType>
              <uap:FileType>.png</uap:FileType>
              <uap:FileType>.tiff</uap:FileType>
              <uap:FileType>.tif</uap:FileType>
            </uap:SupportedFileTypes>
          </uap:FileTypeAssociation>
        </uap:Extension>
      </Extensions>
...
```

where it also registers the uri scheme name `drawboardpdf`, but it seems like it can't be used to open specific files. I tried

```
explorer.exe drawboardpdf:///C:/Users/user/test.pdf
```

but it only opened the app, but not the specified file inside the app.

How can I open a PDF file with Drawboard PDF App from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install wslu
wslview test.pdf
```

Will open your standart PDF viewing App (Drawboard PDF)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).