# How to add Windows Store Apps to PATH?

Tags: windows, terminal, windows-store-app, windows-terminal

I want to add the Windows Terminal (wt) to PATH, as I get the following error if I execute the commands "wt" and "wt.exe":
[image: wt]

My problem is that Micro$oft has apparently added a version number to their folder name. So as soon as they update, the Windows Terminal link changes and it's not in PATH anymore.
It's currently:

> C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_1.15.3465.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe

How can I keep the Windows Terminal in Path, so that I can execute it?
I tried:

1. Turning App execution aliases off and on
2. "Repairing" the Windows Terminal App in the Apps&Features-Settings

Comment: I do not think such apps need to be in the path to execute.  Terminal is in All Apps and it runs fine.  Windows 10 and 11.

Comment: Do you know how they are executed normally? Because it doesn't work for me...

Comment: I am not sure in your case. On my machines, Terminal runs normally and I never bothered adding to path.

Comment: I added Lenovo Vantage (Store App) multiple computers and for sure did not add it to path.

Comment: What you want to do shouldn't be necessary since every child path contained within WindowsApps is defined by default in your PATH variable.

Comment: What does `where.exe wt` give you?

Comment: @Ramhound maybe I deleted it accidentally sometime ago? Can you see the entry in PATH or is it invisible for the user?

Comment: I look in my Environment variables and UWP Apps (the appropriate Windows folder) is int the path by default.   That is why it works.

Comment: @MySurmise - The only way it would have been removed is if you have a habit of editing it yourself, and perhaps, the variable contains to many characters.

Comment: Try looking at a good machine and see if you can add the path back.

Comment: @John Thanks. That worked! Should've got the idea myself, but sometimes you just can't see the forest for the trees :D
The solution was not to add the "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps", but "%userprofile%/appdata/local/microsoft/WindowsApps" to path...

Comment: And I now also remember why that path was deleted: I accidentally installed Python over the Store instead of the official download link and I think to avoid calling the wrong Python, I just deleted WindowsApps from PATH 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*<sub>Already answered via comments, but moving it to an answer (especially since it was what I was going to post before I even read the comments).</sub>*

Windows Terminal (and many other Store apps) create App Execution Aliases, which are essentially "fake `.exe` files to launch the Store app.  These `.exe`'s are created in the user's `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\WindowsApps` folder (a.k.a. `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps`), which should automatically be in the default path.

However, I've seen cases of this folder being accidentally removed from the `Path` before, and I suspect (confirmed in the comments) that this is the case here, since you mention that you even tried toggling the app execution alias without improvement.

Check the `Path` *user variable* (not the System variable).  The easiest access, IMHO, is by:

- Searching for *Path" in the Start menu
- Select *Edit the system environment variables*
- Click the *Environment Variables* button
- Edit the *Path* variable in the *User variables for ...* section, *not* the *System variables* one.

If `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps` or `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\WindowsApps` is missing, add it back in (the first form is the "normal" default).

Side-note:  Even if there isn't an app execution alias for a Store app, you can often create a PowerShell script that will execute it.  You can then place this script in a directory in your path (I use `%USERPROFILE%\.local\bin` to mimic Linux, which I've added to my path).   There is typically a "package family name" that isn't tied to a particular version number that can be used.

See [my answer here](https://superuser.com/a/1753852/1210833) (or some of the other answers on that question) for details on finding the correct command-line.